# Parsing <T extends Interface<T>> and ending a potential infinite cycle

Tags: java, generics, classloader, javac

Consider a class definition that starts with

`class Pokemon extends Playable<Pokemon>`

This is similar to the more common `class Pokemon implements Comparable<Pokemon>`, which just imposes a total ordering on the Pokemons.

Although I have been seeing this and writing this for some time, I realized (after fielding a question) that from a theoretical standpoint at least, there could be a risk of an infinite loop in parsing if one is not careful.

Consider this:
Step 1: The compiler or classloader tries to parse (or load) `Pokemon`, but sees it needs to parse `Playable<.>` first.
Step 2: The compiler then realizes because `Playable` is parameterized by `Pokemon`, it needs to load or parse `Pokemon`. Now we find ourselves going to Step 1, and a never-ending cycle is established.

In practice, we know this is not the case, because it works. So how is cycle broken? My theory is that at the end of Step 2, the compiler or classloader just stops and use a "reference" to Pokemon instead of pulling up the Pokemon source code. But I don't know enough about `javac` or the `Classloaders` to affirm this. Could anyone weigh in?

Comment: Generics are not like C++ templates. The compiler doesn't need to pre-compile the generic so it's not a compile time concern).

Comment: The classloader is smart enough to handle this. Examine its source code to find out how it does it.

Comment: It's compile time concern, but I think oracle guys are not stupid and resolve this. But not sure how.

Comment: I don't see why you need generics to ask this question. What about a simple class with a variable of its own type?

Comment: @shmosel That's a good point - the compiler at least faces a similar challenge there. Would you have inputs on how it's resolved in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to a "loop" in this declaration:

```
class LinkedListNode {
    private String data;
    private LinkedListNode next;
    ...
}
```

In order to process `private LinkedListNode next` field, all the compiler needs to know is that `LinkedListNode` is a type. It does not need to have a complete type at this point, because type name provides enough information to declare the field.

Similarly, when you declare a generic class that refers to its own type as part of its inheritance structure, the compiler does not need a complete type to finish parsing the declaration.

Comment: You might want to use distinctions like parsing vs. name resolving or syntactic vs. semantic analysis to explain that a compiler doesn't need to know everything at once. Your notion of a "complete type" alludes to this, but is quite vague, still.